# How to add padding for vertical line shape in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I have a layer-list background for my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/warm_grey"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="1.5dp"
            android:color="@color/blue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:top="10dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-90">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="@color/blue"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Here I tried to set paddings for the lines above using top, bottom, left and right attributes, and it works for the horizontal line but doesn't work for the vertical one.

How do I add vertical paddings for the vertical line shape?

Comment: Try, inside the shape block, add padding, like stroke/corners/solid

Answer (score 0):

Here is link which is create online button or any view shapes Link : http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Here is code like :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="14dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="#7995A8"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
        android:type="linear" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="60dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try left and right in case of vertical line as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/light_blue"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/warm_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1.5dp"
                android:color="@color/blue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="@color/blue"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: That actually worked, but if the view is not a square, these paddings are applied BEFORE the line is rotated,  so it doesn't seem to be a perfect solution.